# Stateless API with JWT cookie invalidation

Tags: laravel, cookies, stateless

I have been playing for a couple of days with a stateless Laravel API with JWT based authentication, where I store the token in a cookie.

All is well, except for the cookie (in)validation...

I set my cookie like so

```
Cookie::queue(Cookies::NAME, $token, (int) env('COOKIE_VALIDITY'), Cookies::PATH, env('COOKIE_DOMAIN'), env('COOKIE_SECURE'), Cookies::HTTPONLY, Cookies::RAW, Cookies::SAMESITE);

$redirectUrl = $request->query('redirectTo') ?? route('home');
 return redirect($redirectUrl);
```

This works, it does set the cookie.
However, my cookie Expires/Max-Age seems to be one hour behind, always.
`2019-10-12T08:51:35.737Z` (when it is actually 9:51)

The cookies gets sent correctly on all subsequent requests though.

The biggest problem however, is cookie invalidation.
My logout action looks like this

```
return redirect('/login')->withCookies([Cookie::forget(Cookies::NAME)]);
```

The action gets called to, but the cookie remains unchanged.
I also tried with the `cookie()->forget()` helper, this has the same result.

Any clues to what I am doing wrong here?

Ps: I do see that laravel by default adds a session cookie as well, I suppose this is normal, due to the fact that I reach the site as an anonymous user and therefor receive a session for that?
Im asking because the challange for me is to have a full stateless API that only uses server side rendered login page and then redirects back to some kind of SPA.

All help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To whom it may concern, I have found the problem.
Apparently, specifying the cookie name is not sufficient.

```
return redirect('/login')->withCookies([Cookie::forget(Cookies::NAME, Cookies::PATH, env('COOKIE_DOMAIN'))]);
```

Works perfectly.